# Why is the Exponent for Float (32 Bit) in Java -126 and not -128?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754, single-precision

32 Bit Standard:

1 Bit for Positive/Negative value of the number. 8 Bits for the Exponent and 24 Bits for Mantisse.

8 Bits for Exponent, that means 1 * 2^7 + 1 * 2^6 + ... = 255
When the maximum Exponent is 127, then the minimum Exponent should be -128, so that 126 + 128 = 255.

But why is Java saying that the minimum Exponent is -126? 255 - (127+126)= 2, so there are two numbers which we are not using.

Comment: Java `float` is just standard IEEE 754 single precision floating point numbers. This [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) details the format specification. I do not have the time to excerpt relevant part to compose an answer, so you may need to go find it yourself.

Comment: @Optimal _"why is Java saying that the minimum Exponent is -126?"_ Please provide the link to the page where this is documented.

Comment: Here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number has a 'bias', whatever is in those bits? First subtract `0x7F` from it to get your value. The lowest exponent is reached by using value `0x01`: `0x01 - 0x7F = 1 - 127 = -126`. The highest is reached with value `0xFE`: `0xFE - 0x7F = 254 - 127 = 127`.

But, what happened to exponent values `0x00` and `0xFF`? That's why there are 254 and not 256 unique exponents available: Those two are special magic and not available normally. Exponent 0 is both used to encode 0 (if the number for the fraction is also 0), or for so-called subnormal numbers, which are numbers extremely close to 0.

`0xFF` is used for special values; this is how floats can store `NaN` and both infinities.

Comment: Why are the subnormal numbers “so-called” subnormal numbers? Are they not in fact less than the normal numbers? Are you expressing doubt about whether they are in fact subnormal numbers?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think that's "so-called" in the sense of introducing a term, rather than in the sense of casting doubt on the appropriateness of that term. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so-called

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Indeed, but it is not good to use an ambiguous term that may be pejorative. It would be better to simply put it in italics to convey it is a technical term that is being introduced.

Comment: I addressed many of your questions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924829/1766831

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 exponent sequences that encode special values. All 0s encodes either 0 or subnormals, depending on the mantissa. All 1s encodes either Infinity or NaNs. This means instead of 256 exponent sequences, there are, like you said, 254 sequences to encode normal numbers.

Thus, it makes sense that exponent 00000001 encodes power -126 and 11111110 encodes power 127. This is the exponent range for normal numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Could you explain the last sentence _Thus, it makes sense that exponent 00000001 encodes power -126 and 11111110 encodes power 127. This is the exponent range for normal numbers._? How do you encode [0...254] values as  [-126...127] ?

Comment: @snr, My answer was in response to the original question, which was why there are 2 sequences that don't seem to be used. Your question is how the exponent is decoded, which is completely different. The short answer is that an offset of -127 needs to be applied to decode the exponent. A more detailed explanation can be found on the wiki page I linked.